# SwiftUI EKEventEditViewController fields not editable

Tags: ios, calendar, swiftui, eventkit

I have been trying to use EKEventEditViewController with SwiftUI. I tried to follow some suggestions from dev forums as to how to go about adding it with the help of a UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapper with a Coordinator. I am adding the code below.

The EKEventEditViewController is presented correctly but the problem I'm facing is that only some of the fields are editable. I'm attaching a gif showing the interactions.

Has anyone faced this issue ?
Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import EventKitUI

let eventStore = EKEventStore()

struct NewEventGenerator: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

typealias UIViewControllerType = EKEventEditViewController

@Binding var isShowing: Bool

var theEvent = EKEvent.init(eventStore: eventStore)

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewEventGenerator>) -> EKEventEditViewController {

    let controller = EKEventEditViewController()
    controller.event = theEvent
    controller.eventStore = eventStore
    controller.editViewDelegate = context.coordinator

    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: NewEventGenerator.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewEventGenerator>) {
    uiViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(isShowing: $isShowing)
}

class Coordinator : NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, EKEventEditViewDelegate {

    @Binding var isVisible: Bool

    init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isVisible = isShowing
    }

    func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
        switch action {
        case .canceled:
            isVisible = false
        case .saved:
            do {
                try controller.eventStore.save(controller.event!, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
            }
            catch {
                print("Event couldn't be created")
            }
            isVisible = false
        case .deleted:
            isVisible = false
        @unknown default:
            isVisible = false
        }
    }
}}
```

[image: Here is the recording]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. Literally copy-pasted your code added requestAccess & descriptions in Info.plist.

[image: demo]

Full tested module, for the case if something might be helpful.

```
import SwiftUI
import EventKitUI

let eventStore = EKEventStore()

struct NewEventGenerator: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = EKEventEditViewController

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var theEvent: EKEvent

    init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>) {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { allow, error in
            print("Result: \(allow) or [\(error.debugDescription)]")
        }

        theEvent = EKEvent.init(eventStore: eventStore)

        _isShowing = isShowing
    }


func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewEventGenerator>) -> EKEventEditViewController {

    let controller = EKEventEditViewController()
    controller.event = theEvent
    controller.eventStore = eventStore
    controller.editViewDelegate = context.coordinator

    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: NewEventGenerator.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NewEventGenerator>) {
    uiViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(isShowing: $isShowing)
}

class Coordinator : NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, EKEventEditViewDelegate {

    @Binding var isVisible: Bool

    init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isVisible = isShowing
    }

    func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
        switch action {
        case .canceled:
            isVisible = false
        case .saved:
            do {
                try controller.eventStore.save(controller.event!, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
            }
            catch {
                print("Event couldn't be created")
            }
            isVisible = false
        case .deleted:
            isVisible = false
        @unknown default:
            isVisible = false
        }
    }
}}

struct TestEventKitViewInSheet: View {     // just created in ContentView body
    @State private var showIt = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Events") { showIt = true }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showIt) {
                NewEventGenerator(isShowing: $showIt)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats strange! I was checking on iOS 13 but I'll update to the latest beta and see if it behaves differently. Thanks for checking :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I guess I'm missing some other key pointer. I've only specified NSCalendarsUsageDescription in plist file, any other configurations that you might have done ? 
Since it works for you I will mark it as resolved and share the bounty.

Comment: I added as well NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, just in case

Comment: Just tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - works as well. Maybe try it with new empty project.

Comment: Wasted another entire day trying to figure this out. Eventually created a new project, copied files from my original project and it worked ‍♂️